# Accessing a local file which changes it's name based on date and month in php

Tags: php, email

I'm super new to php so hopefully this is a simple enough question for a pro to answer. I use got-your-back to download specific gmail to my local machine each morning. Today's back-up is saved in the path gyb/GYB-GMail-Backup-xxxxx@gmail.com/2015/5/11 and the file is 11-81.eml

To test my script I simply copied 11-81.eml to the same folder as my php file and it works fine, but I am having trouble referencing the file on the local disk.. Tomorrow's file will be in gyb/GYB-GMail-Backup-xxxxx@gmail.com/2015/5/12 and the file will be called 12-82.eml

so far I have this code but it does not seem to find the file..

```
$pathname = 'Users/????/gyb/GYB-GMail-Backup-xxxxx@gmail.com/2015/'.$m .'/'.$d.'/';

echo $pathname;
$filename = $pathname.$d.'-81.eml';
$texttofind = "Subject:";
$file = new SplFileObject($filename);
$bort = FALSE;
$grabbed = FALSE;

foreach($file as $line) {
if(strpos($line, $texttofind) !== FALSE) {
    $grabbed = $line;


    } 
}
echo $grabbed;
    if(strpos($grabbed, "ref12345") === FALSE) {
        echo "ref12345 does not exist in this file";

}
```

I have not yet figured out how to change the -81.eml to -82.eml but I have a hunch this should not be too challenging.. The tricky bit for me is referencing the exact folder and file.

Thank you for your help.. I have searched for this answer as requested but apologies if the is a super noob question.
Kind regards
P

Comment: Start by adding a `/` in front of `Users/[...]` => `/Users/????/gyb/GYB-GMail[...]`

Comment: Seriously that was all it needed... Facepalm moment. Thank you.. :-)